# Nested css background image doesn't change after 3 levels

Tags: html, css

I've a nested list of divs, after the third level it doesn't seem to update the style.

This is the css:

```css
.list_unordered .list_item {
     background:none transparent no-repeat 3px 7px !important;
}
.list_unordered[data-attr-listtype="bullet"] .list_item {
     background-image:url("../Images/list_bullet.png") !important;
}
.list_unordered[data-attr-listtype="square"] .list_item {
    background-image:url("../Images/list_square.png") !important;
}
.list_unordered[data-attr-listtype="dash"] .list_item {
    background-image:url("../Images/list_dash.png") !important;
}
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<div class="list_unordered" data-attr-listtype="bullet">
  <div class="list_item">
    <span class="text">Rondje 1</span>
    <div class="list_unordered" data-attr-listtype="square">
      <div class="list_item">
        <span class="text">Blokje 2</span>
        <div class="list_unordered" data-attr-listtype="dash">
          <div class="list_item">
            <span class="text">Streepje 3</span>
            <div class="list_unordered" data-attr-listtype="square">
              <div class="list_item">
                <span class="text">Blokje 4</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list_item">
    <span class="text">Rondje 1</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the result:
[image: Result]
As you can see the fourth item should be a square but it gets rendered as a dash.
What is the reason of this? And how can I fix this?

Comment: is it possible that this is happening because the square css rule already applied to the outermost div, which is overwritten by the two following ones, and when the CSS will be applied to the innermost div it is already on there? I'm not sure though, if you could provide a jsfiddle for this i could test it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a quick solution:

```
.list_unordered .list_item {
    background:none transparent no-repeat 3px 7px !important;
}
.list_unordered[data-attr-listtype="bullet"] > .list_item {
    background-image:url("../Images/list_bullet.png") !important;
}
.list_unordered[data-attr-listtype="square"] > .list_item {
    background-image:url("../Images/list_square.png") !important;
}
.list_unordered[data-attr-listtype="dash"] > .list_item {
    background-image:url("../Images/list_dash.png") !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The three CSS rules all have exactly the same specificity, so the last one will be applied (the one with the streepje). How deep an element is nested inside another element is not part of the specificity.

Comment: Does the attribute specified in the square brackets not separate them somehow ?

Comment: @grimmus No, that's not how it works. The innermost span is inside a div with `data-attr-listtype="dash"`, so that's the rule that gets applied. Yes, it is ALSO inside a div with `data-attr-listtype="square"`, but the rule for the dash gets applied, because it comes last in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

If you're basically creating nested lists, you should use the correct HTML elements, see [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hNmSU/), you can also then clean up your HTML and add CSS to style automatically without needing the `data` attributes.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>Level 1
        <ul>
            <li>Level 2
                <ul>
                    <li>Level 3
                        <ul>
                            <li>Level 4</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li{
    list-style-type:circle;
}

li li {
    list-style-type:square;
}

li li li {
    list-style-type:disc;
}

li li li li{
    list-style-type:lower-alpha;
}
```

Comment: this might be a way to accomplish the same thing, but it does not explain why the original post does not behave as expected

Comment: You are correct, I am creating nested lists.
Sadly, I have to do it this way because of the JavaScript plugin I am using here.